# asymptotic behavior of a function f bounded above by $\log_2(xf(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a positive integer n, we can look at all the subsets $ S \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$ with the property that, for any two sets $A,B \subseteq S$,
$$sum(A) = sum(B) \implies A = B.$$
For example, when $n=100$, the set $ \{1,2,4,8,16,32,64\}$ possesses this property, because the binary representation of a natural number is unique. For a given positive integer n, we can define the set of these subsets as
$$A(n) = \big\{ S \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\} \text{ such that for all } A,B \subseteq S, sum(A) = sum(B) \implies A = B \big\}.$$ If we define the function

$$f(n) = \max_{S \in A(n)}|S| $$

to be the cardinality of the largest such sets, then we can get a lower bound for $f$ by looking at the set of powers of 2 less than or equal to $n$. This gives the bound
$$\log_2(n) < 1 + \left \lfloor \log_2(n) \right \rfloor \leq f(n) $$

On the other hand, for any set $S$ of size $|S| = k$, there are $2^k$ subsets, and if each of the elements of $S$ is drawn from the numbers $1$ through $n$, then each subsets sums to a number between $0$ and $kn$, inclusive. So by the pigeonhole principle, $f(n)$ cannot be so large that
$$2^{f(n)} > nf(n) + 1,$$
because then two subsets would have to map to the same sum. Therefore it must be that
$$f(n) \leq \log_2 \big(nf(n) +1\big)$$

for all positive integers $n$. By virtue of its definition, $f$ must be non-decreasing. I'm trying to understand this function $f$. Can you give an asymptotic formula? (or better yet, an exact one?)

NOTE: Since reading some helpful comments, I've given a little more context to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are you sure that f is non decreasing?

Comment: $f(1)\gt 0$. Evaluating the given expression gives $\log_2(n) < f(n) < \log_2n+\log_2f(n)\implies 0\lt f(n)-\log_2n \lt \log_2f(n)\implies 2^{f(n)-\log_2n}\lt f(n)$ for all $n$.
Here, $f(n)\gt 1$ for all $n$. $2^{f(1)}\lt f(1)$, which is not possible.

Comment: good point Koro. I added some context to justify why f is non decreasing, and I tweaked the inequalities so that the contradiction you found goes away. Thanks for pointing that out!